# Docker images/containers taking up space despite clean up

Tags: docker

I noticed that Docker appears to be using a large amount of disk space. I can see the directory `/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/default` is `27.4GB`

I recently cleaned up all of the images and containers I wasn't using. Now, when I run `docker ps` I see that no images are running.

```
~ $ docker ps
```

I can also see that I have 2 containers available.

```
~ $ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
42332s42d3        cds-abm        "/bin/bash"         2 weeks ago         Exited (130) 2 weeks ago                       evil_shockley
9ssd64ee41        tes-abm        "/bin/bash"         2 weeks ago         Exited (130) 2 weeks ago                       lonely_brattain
```

I can then see I have 3 images.

```
~ $ docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ghr/get  latest              6708fffdd4dfa        2 weeks ago         2.428 GB
<none>                <none>              96c5974ddse18        2 weeks ago         2.428 GB
fdbh/ere         latest              bf1da53766b1        2 weeks ago         2.225 GB
```

How can these be taking up nearly `30GB`?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not removing the volumes created by the containers when you stop the container. In the future, use `-v` when you remove the containers.

```
docker rm -v <container-id>
```

Regrading cleaning up the space, you have to ssh into docker-machine and remove all volumes created. To do so,

```
docker-machine ssh default
sudo -i # You may not get permission to enter in to volumes directory
cd /var/lib/docker/volumes
rm -rf *
```

Make sure none of your containers are currently running. Also, make sure that you don't need any of these volumes for later use (like DB containers).

Comment: Since Docker 1.9, you don't need to SSH into the machine; you can just delete the dangling volumes with `docker volume ls -f dangling=true -q | xargs docker volume rm`.

Comment: Note that `dangling=true` also matches named volumes that are not currently mounted. This can result in irrevocable data loss.